# How to send CLOB parameter from C# to Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, clob

I'm new here. I have a problem. I want to execute this code in C#:

```
string XMLData = File.ReadAllText(App.FolderImport + "\\" + FileName);

Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Command.CommandText = "PKG_DATA_EXCHANGE.IMPORT_DATA";
Command.Parameters.Add("pID_USER_M", OracleType.Number).Value = App.User.IdUser;
Command.Parameters.Add("pFILE_NAME", OracleType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
Command.Parameters.Add("pXMLDATA", OracleType.Clob).Value = XMLDataString;

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It works fine for small XMLDataString, but if it is bigger then I get exception 
`ORA-01460`.

I understand that it is linked somehow to CLOB problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

I was searching for such problem here, but I had no luck.

Please any help, links or code will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other reported causes of the ORA-01460 as well:

- Incompatible character sets can cause an ORA-01460
- Using SQL Developer, attempting to pass a string to a bind variable value in excess of 4000 bytes can result in an ORA-01460
- With ODP, users moving from the 10.2 client and 10.2 ODP to the 11.1 client and 11.1.0.6.10 ODP reported an ORA-01460 error (this was a bug that should be fixed by patching ODP to the most recent version)

It appears, according to information on bug 5872943, that the ORA-01460 associated with ODP.NET, while not an ODP error, persisted through database version 11.2 where it has been reported as fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create an **OracleClob** object that receives an **Open() connection** and then we write the value as an **Array of Bytes** to it.

If you are using **EF** and **Context** you can access the conectionString as follows:

`string connectionString = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;`

The code would look like this:

```
using OracleConnection connection = new(connectionString);
    
try
{
    connection.Open(); //required
    
    byte[] arrayByte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(audit.AuditRecord);
    OracleClob oracleClob = new (connection);
    oracleClob.Write(arrayByte, 0, arrayByte.Length);

    var parameters = new OracleParameter[]
    {
        new OracleParameter("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, valueParam1, ParameterDirection.Input),
        new OracleParameter("param_clob", OracleDbType.Clob, oracleClob, ParameterDirection.Input),
        new OracleParameter("p_refcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
    };

    OracleCommand cmd= new("SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME", connection)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    };

    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    //getting the returned values
    var result = (OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters["p_refcursor"].Value;
    var reader = result.GetDataReader();

    reader.Read();

    // To access the returned values

    //reader.GetOracleValue(0)
    //reader.GetOracleValue(1)
    //reader.GetOracleValue(2)
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```